# Grails UrlMappings with "-" as a separator

Tags: grails, url-mapping

I want to separate String params with a "-" in a url.

I had configurate UrlMappings with:

```
name friendlyurl: "/${productId}-${title}_url"{
  controller = "product"
  action = "index"
}
```

The productId is in the form stringnumber, like *ESE123*

The product controller needs the param productId.
It works with url like:

ESE1234-asdlashdlasj_url

But not with

ESE1234-Adidas-shoes_url

In the last case it take ESE1234-Adidas as a productId.

Maybe grails is using eager regexp matcher.

How to I disable this eager regexp in order to only take to the first "-"? Or maybe other way maybe.

Answer (score 2):

why dont you just do

```
name friendlyurl: "/${productId}/${title}_url"{
  controller = "product"
  action = "index"
}
```

and if the "-" is so important, just concat it back together in the controller

Comment: In the url is important the "-"

Comment: take a look at this, you might have problems with your approach http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GRAILS-3202